# what are the cons of using unix timestamp as an order ID?

Tags: php, mysql, unix, timestamp

I am designing a shopping project and am thinking about using the unix timestamp as the order ID. I know I can use mySQL incremental numbers to use as order ID like 10001, 10002, etc. but I don't want everybody to know how many orders there really are.

Is this a safe way to do it? I obviously don't expect more than 1 order per second, so I should be safe, right?

```
function check_number(){

$unique_number = time();
$exists = $this->count_rows('orders', "WHERE order_id='" . $unique_number . "'");

if ($exists >0){
    $results = check_number();
}
else{
    $results = $unique_number;
    return $results;
}
}
```

Comment: Put a `sleep(1)` before the recursive call to be sure that the time will change.

Comment: Or just use a loop where you increment `$unique_number` until you succeed.

Comment: There is no reason to use your row identifier as your "order number", and probably at least a few good reasons NOT to. Generally speaking, users should never see internal row identifiers.

Comment: @Uueerdo Why would it matter if a user sees a database id? Knowing an id shouldn't open up any attack vectors, or there's a serious flaw in the system's design. Security through obfuscation is not something you should rely on. RESTful apis use database ids all the time.

Comment: I'm not so much talking about security through obscurity. At the code/api level sure, expose it as a "handle". I'm talking about numbers shown on webpages or printed on invoices. That number means very little to users, if it ever needs provided (for support) it becomes easy to guess valid ones by less honest ones. Plus, there eventually becomes the temptation to make the number more "user friendly" which now starts to affect your database design. (All of a sudden someone wants invoice numbers with letters, or to a have regional prefix with each region starting from 1, etc...)

Comment: @Uueerdo True, but you could just as easily add a checksum to your ids shown on invoices, and again, just knowing or guessing an invoice id shouldn't allow a person to access sensitive information. But you're right in that there generally are no pros in using a db id as an invoice id. I just don't think there are any cons either, should it happen to be convenient to you for some reason to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much more robust solution would be to use PHP's [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function. It hides the number of orders in your system, but it wont go belly-up if two or more orders happen to come in at the same second.

As for the actual question: no, it's not safe to use unix timestamps as unique ids for semi-random events, like users making orders. However unlikely it may be, why leave in the possibility of a collision when it can be easily avoided?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it as there is a possibility that two orders are made in the same second. Use the default increment and add/subtract the ID by a fixed number so the users sees a larger number.

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
$ID -= 183727; // subtract offset
// Do mysql stuff
// Build an ID for an URL
$ID += 183727;
echo 'http://../test.php?order=' .$ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make a crontab that will do 
   `ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = max_id + <something>;` and move this  randomly every day or hour (not the best thing to do though); OR you can put randomly ids (more than current max id) in the inserts.
2. If you want to keep integers in the DB, you can use `base64_` family with a salt.
3. You can use uniques slugs in URLs
4. You can use `com_create_guid` or similar functions or even generate random strings / numbers, but be sure you have a "UNIQUE" constraint in the database.

---

The problem with "timestamp" is about lots of concurrent operations it won't be unique for a certain time-frame; you can use microseconds and add some random numbers at the end - that can help.